# Scaling number e+xx to e+00 in python

Tags: python, scaling

I want to scale the numbers from e+xx to e+00. For example, `1003 -> 1.003` or `0.00372 -> 3.72`. How can I change these numbers in python? (It is good if the code is one line)

Comment: `float(('%e' % float(1003)).split('e')[0])` and `float(('%e' % float(0.00372)).split('e')[0])`

Comment: Get the base 10 logarithm of the number and round it down. Then divide by that power of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not in one line, but pretty understandable tho (using recursion)

```
def e_00(num):
    if 0 < abs(num) < 1:
        return e_00(num * 10)
    elif abs(num) > 10:
        return e_00(num / 10)
    else:
        return num
```